# Como converter uma cadeia em hexadecimal?

Tags: prisma

Quero converter uma cadeia de caracteres em hexadecimal:

```
cadeia = "blablabla"
```

Comment: Não vejo como a pergunta ou a resposta podem ser uteis no formato que estão agora.

Comment: Sua intenção é legal. Conteúdo de qualidade pro site é sempre uma boa ideia. Mas tome cuidado com a frequência/quantidade de publicações. Tente manter em mente a utilidade (além da qualidade em si, é claro) de suas perguntas/respostas para os visitantes do site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode ser feito de duas maneiras utilizando a função [formate()](http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz/blog/tutorial-principais-funcoes-prisma/):

```
cadeia = "blablabla"
hex = cadeia:formate("%X")
```

Ou dessa outra maneira também é possível atingir o mesmo resultado:

```
cadeia = "blablabla"
hex = string.formate("%X", cadeia)
```

Comment: Poderia linkar a doc das funções, valorizaria a resposta.

Comment: E explicar o que essa função faz(caso faça algo alem disso), o que são esses caracteres %X ai. A resposta está muito vaga, você entende, mas precisa partir do pressuposto de que quem está lendo pode não entender a linguagem ;)

Answer (score 1):

A função **string.formate** é similar a sprintf() do C. Em Prisma, ela formata uma string com argumentos variados e retorna a string formatada;
ex: s = string.formate("horário: %02d:%02d\n",6,30);
agora o valor de s será "horário: 06:30\n";

O caractere "%X" formata um inteiro em hexadecimal maiúsculo;
colocando um 0 e 2 entre o % e X preenche com zero a esquerda (00, 01, 02 etc);

Para mais detalhes dê um ctrl + F na página: [manual básico](http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz/blog/manual-basico/)

[site oficial da linguagem](http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz/blog/)

Abaixo segue o código que fiz para converter cada byte da string em hexa, livre para usar, adaptar para cada necessidade, ou melhorar:

```
local string_em_hexa; //declarando uma variável local para a função;
local string_em_hexa_simples;

funcao principal(arg) //similar a função main do C ou Main do Java;
  local str = "blablabla";
  imprima( string_em_hexa(str) );
  //ou:
  imprima( string_em_hexa_simples(str));
  retorne 0; //retornando 0 para o sistema operacional;
fim

//Dois modos de fazer (duas funções):

//função não está limitada ao tamanho da pilha, mas é um pouco mais lenta;
funcao string_em_hexa(str)
  se tipo(str) <> 'string' entao 
    retorne falso, 'Erro, espera-se string em vez de ' .. tipo(arg); 
  fim
  local hexa =  '';
  local c;//declarando variável c como local; em Prisma variáveis não tem tipo fixo.
  para i=1,#str inicio  //o sinal # ao lado de uma string retorna seu comprimento;
    c = string.cod(str,i);//converte cada char (byte) para número
    hexa = hexa .. string.formate('%02X ',c); //formata o número para (%x) hexadecimal retornando em string;
  fim   
  retorne hexa;
fim 

//esta função é limitada pelo número máximo (999000) de indices do stack (pilha) de retorno; mas é mais rápida
//boa para strings não muito grandes (menores que 999000);
funcao string_em_hexa_simples(str)
  se tipo(str) <> 'string' entao 
    retorne falso, 'Erro, espera-se string em vez de ' .. tipo(arg); 
  senao
    retorne string.formate( string.nconcat('%02X ',#str), string.cod(str,1,#str)  );
  fim  
fim

//uma solução seria fazer uma função que usa blocos de 999000 bytes por vez, com isso
//teriamos rapidez e não estaria limitada ao tamanho da pilha;
```

Saída:

62 6C 61 62 6C 61 62 6C 61

62 6C 61 62 6C 61 62 6C 61

**PS.: Uma outra forma mais simples e rápida:**

```
local s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

funcao Hex(s)
  local strfmt = string.formate;
  local cod = cod;
  retorne (s:troque('[\000-\255]', funcao (c) 
                             retorne strfmt('%X ',cod(c)); 
                          fim))
fim 

imprima(Hex(s));
```